# dynamically add EventListener doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

When I try to dynamically fill a wrapper element with HTML elements, and then add an EventListener for that element, it only uses the last value.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 sW="";
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = "test div number "+i;
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {alert("t:"+i);});
  document.getElementById('wrap').appendChild(e);
  } 
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `var` keeps the the reference to the variable. Use `let` instead.